# AssetBundles with shaders that contain #include to cg/hlsl

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a shader that contains some #includes to other cg/hlsl scripts.
If i put that shader into an AssetBundle, how am i suppose to handle the cg/hlsl scripts?

Are they not necessary anymore because they are compiled into the shader during the AssetBundle build process?
Unity version is 5.6.6f2

Or do i have to put the cg/hlsl scripts into the AssetBundle too?
If that is the case, how do I load them during runtime such that the Shader finds them?

Someone suggested me to inline them, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaders are not compiled into the assetbundle, they are threated like any other script and can thus not be compiled into the bundle.

Under project settings > Graphics > Built-in shader settings there is a section "always included shaders". If you add the shaders in there they will be included into your build. So as long as your assetbundle has a reference to the shader when compiling the bundle it should have no trouble using the correct shader once you instantiate an object.

Inlining your shader shouldn't be necessary at all.